# Required type Integer provided BigDecimal Java compareTo()

Tags: java, integer, bigdecimal, compareto

[Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DACtb.png)

In the following method I am trying to use a compareTo() to compare getErclasCurrErWtPerValNo() which is an Integer and getErclasHrWorkEligNo() is a BigDecimal. I am not having any luck casting or using intValue(). How can this be resolved?

```
public Integer getErclasCurrErWtPerValNo() {
        return this.erclasCurrErWtPerValNo;
    }

public BigDecimal getErclasHrWorkEligNo() {
        return this.erclasHrWorkEligNo;
    }


if (StringUtils.isEmpty(erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasHrWorkEligNo())) {
    errors.rejectValue(fieldPrefix + "ebErClasses.erclasHrWorkEligNo", getSectionName(),
            "Minimum Working Hours Per Week is required.");
} else if (erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasCurrErWtPerValNo().compareTo(erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasHrWorkEligNo())){
    errors.rejectValue(fieldPrefix + "ebErClasses.erclasHrWorkEligNo", getSectionName(),
            "Hours can not be below " + erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasHrWorkEligNo().intValue() + ".");
}
```

Comment: Your class is presumably declared as Comparable<Integer> by mistake. You need to show the class definition of the value returned by `getErclasCurrErWtPerValNo`. The code you've shown isn't enough

Comment: @Michael Thanks Michael I am adding these now

Comment: Oh right. I see now. Probably better to invert the comparison. Integer can only be compared to Integer, but you can't convert a BigDecimal to an Integer without maybe losing the decimal part. `erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasHrWorkEligNo().compareTo(new BigDecimal(erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasCurrErWtPerValNo()))`

Comment: @Michael Now it says required type boolean provided int

Comment: Look at the documentation for that method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html It returns a tri-state. Less than, equal or greater than. You are putting it inside an `if` which expects one of 2 states: true or false. If you want to see if they're the same, add `== 0` after it.

Comment: @Michael what would <= 0 achieve versus == 0?

Comment: `<= 0` would mean if the ErclasHrWorkEligNo (the one on the left) is less than or equal to the ErclasCurrErWtPerValNo (the one on the right)

Answer (score -1):

BigDecimal as a intValue() Method wich "Converts this BigDecimal to an int." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

this would work:

```
erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasCurrErWtPerValNo().compareTo(erpp.getEbErClasses().getErclasHrWorkEligNo.intValue() == 0
```

I would add a null check

Comment: If my BigDecimal has value of 3.5 and I call `intValue()`, I will get the integer 3. If I compare that to another Integer 3, it will appear as though 3.5 == 3. You shouldn't use `intValue` here because you're throwing away the decimal. You're effectively rounding down. The correct way to solve this is to convert the Integer to BigDecimal, not the other way around.